# Is there difference between `Class.newInstance()` and `Class()` in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a any functional difference in Kotlin between those?

```kotlin
class Foo {
   companion object {
      fun newInstance() = Foo()
   }
}

// Create new instance somewhere else
val foo = Foo.newInstance()
```

and

```kotlin
class Foo {
}

// Create new instance somewhere else
val foo = Foo()
```

I think that the first approach is just adding more boilerplate code and taking more memory because of companion object. Am I right?

Note: I am in Android environment and `Foo` is actually an `Fragment` in my case, if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

There is no advantage to the first block of code in most cases.

However, in the case of Android Fragments, there is a pattern that you never use the constructor directly to create a Fragment. This is because the Android framework needs to be able to instantiate your Fragment on your behalf when it is recreating the Fragment, and it will only do this by using the empty (zero arguments) constructor. Therefore, when you need to pass arguments to a new Fragment, instead of creating a constructor for that, you create a factory function that creates the fragment with the empty constructor and then passes the arguments by adding them to the Fragment's bundle.

When you don't need any arguments passed to your new Fragment in this way, there's no actual need for the factory function instead of a constructor. However, some people do it that way anyway for consistency. Whether you want to follow this pattern is totally up to you.

Answer (score 1):

At the documentation there is no need to companion objects
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#kotlin

Comment: So I cannot remove `newInstance()` from Fragment and just call `Foo()`? It is not the same thing? I do not have any arguments.

Comment: So when I will use the second example in my original question, there is a possibility, that app will crash sometimes?

Comment: I made some research and figured out that it is just a recommendation to use static instance method the important part is we have to make public 0 parameter constructor so your code is valid I think but recommended one is making static instance factory method.

Comment: Sure, but how I said, seems like pointless boilerplate to me then if it is not actually needed for 0 argument constructors.

Comment: The latest documentation is not using companion objects so you are right I edited my answer

Comment: Weird is, that when you create new "Fragment + ViewModel" example project in latest Android Studio, it still uses `newInstance` in companion object...